# Как установить названия столбцов в виджете QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2, qtablewidget, horizontalheaderlabels

Потребовалось установить пользовательские названия столбцов в `QTableWidget`.

Подскажите, какой функцией это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

> void QTableWidget::**setHorizontalHeaderLabels**(const QStringList &labels)
>
> Устанавливает метки горизонтального заголовка с помощью labels.

```
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['V1','V2','V3','V4','V5'])
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, \
    QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Example(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(4, 5)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5']) 
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget) 

        for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            for column in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(f"Item {row}-{column}")
                item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.resize(550, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если хочешь, чтобы название было аккуратно посередине

```
header = table.horizontalHeader()
header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, QTableWidgetItem("Название"))
```